PyCharm unresolved attribute reference
When inverting a boolean mask, PyCharm shows an inspection warning Unresolved attribute reference 'sum' for class 'int'. It seems it does not know that the inverted boolean mask maintains the sum() method.
Questions: What is the reason for this behavior in this specific case? Why does it not show the same warning for the original boolean mask? How can the inspection warning be avoided?
Example code:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Number': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})

cond = (df['Number'] <= 5)

a = cond.sum()
# PyCharm shows "Unresolved attribute reference 'sum' for class 'int'"
b = (~cond).sum()

print(a)
print(b)


One way to solve that is to hit ALT+ENTER to either ignore unresolved references to int.sum or attribute error for int. But that is a bad idea.
A much better and elegant way to resolve the warning is to cast the result of inversion to pandas Series object explicitly:
b = pd.Series(~cond).sum()

This happens because the base definition of __invert__ returns int so the inferred type is int. Pycharm does not know how __invert__ was overridden by pandas, so it assumes its return type is int after inversion.

It works, but casting to a pandas Series with ~cond already being a Series feels very redundant and makes the code a bit clunkier to read.
If I may ask, why does PyCharm not know how the ~ operator acts on cond, given that it should have the methods and overrides defined in the Series class?

Good question. Idk, maybe the files are not indexed. ~ is a syntactic sugar for calling invert, maybe pycharm does not look deep enouht? You could go to jetbrains Q&A forum or something or open an issue and there.
